# JQuery Slide function is n't behaving at all for data from DB

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a database with two tables, each has three rows and both are connected by id. i executed them in .php so that each row in table_1(question) has its replies in table_2(answers).

Ans now i tried to put a SLIDEUP/SLIDEDOWN function for the answers triggered by buttons.
But unfortunately something is missing...

My Code as follows::

```
            <div id="a" name="a">
        <small><p><?php echo $row2["date"]; ?></p></small>
        <p><B><big><font color= #ba4a00> A:</font></B></big> <small><?php echo $row2["answer"]; ?></small></br></p>
        </div>

<button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
<button class="btn2">Slide down</button>

<script type='text/javascript'>
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btn2").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        $('[name="a"]').slideDown();
        $(this).parent().$('[name="a"]').slideDown();
        $(this).hide();


        });
    $(".btn1").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().$('[name="a"]').slideUp();
        $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the result when you execute your code?

Comment: I am getting buttons but no action of slide up or down...

Comment: You're also getting an error in the web console, if you care to look. jQuery objects don't have a `$` function, so ` $(this).parent().$('[name="a"]').slideDown();` throws an error trying to call `undefined` as a function. You mean ` $(this).parent().find('[name="a"]').slideDown();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your web console, you'll see an error there about trying to call `undefined` as a function, because of this:

```
$(this).parent().$('[name="a"]').slideDown();
```

`$(this).parent()` returns a jQuery object. jQuery objects don't have a `$` property.

You probably meant

```
$(this).parent().find('[name="a"]').slideDown();
```

---

Side note: From the code, it seems likely to me that this structure containing the div and buttons is repeated more than once on the page. If so, you need to remove the `id="a"` on the div, as you cannot have the same ID on more than one element.

Comment: Thanks .,.,.. that solved the slide function.. and in my code.. i added this.(hide) too which i meant is to hide the slide down button when it is clicked and show slide up button parallelly vice versa.. for this what should i be changing in the code?..

Comment: @user6779766: The code does nothing to show the other button. So you'll want to add that, for instance in `btn1`: `$(this).siblings(".btn2").show();`

Comment: @user6779766: All of this could be done with CSS transitions by adding and removing a class to the parent.

Comment: Please check the updated code... it works perfectly nice. except that at the  loading of the page, both button are visible and i would like to have the slideup fucntion running at the start/lwhen page loads..

Comment: @user6779766: Questions on Stack Overflow are not supposed to be moving targets. I've rolled back the edit. The answer above answers the question you asked. I suggest you work with things a bit more, maybe do a couple more tutorials, and then if you're still having trouble making the buttons appear/disappear, post a question about that showing your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery functions usually return a jQuery object so you can easily chain the actions. In your code you call`$(this).parent().$('[name="a"]').slideDown()` which is actually a kind of nonsence. The `$('[name="a"=')` does not belong there.

I'd suppose you want to call the `$('[name="a"]').slideDown()` part to slid the contents of the `div` down. If you want to do this, then the call to the `parent()` function seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: *"I'd suppose you want to call the $('[name="a"]').slideDown()"* That would slide them *all* down. I think the OP just wants to slide down the one inside the same parent as the button.

Comment: True, but OP has shown only one div with a `name='a'` attribute

Comment: Indeed, but the code implies multiple, and the question uses the plural when referring to them.

Comment: OP just has to fix their question.